# Dill Seeds Molding?

Tags: seeds, urban-gardening, dill

I had collected dill seeds from my dill plants. I had not dried the plants when I took the seeds, I just took the seeds right off the plant and put them in a paper envelope. I stored them in a dark, but not so cool place. I harvested the seeds about September 18 and just recently looked at the seeds a few days ago. I noticed that the seeds had some sort of a white fungus on them. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Keep the seeds dry and maybe some will still be viable. Dont leave in closed plastic bag.

Comment: Alright, thank you!